# How to escape an @ sign in the password field of an smb:// URL

Tags: bash, samba, escaping

I'm trying to write a bash script in which I connect to a samba server, by getting the username and password, then saying $username:$password@SERVERNAME.

However, this will fail if the password has an @ in it.  Is there a way to escape the @ out of the password in bash?

Thanks in advance

Update:
I'm setting up this network printer

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER -v smb://$username:$password@SERVER -E
```

and it works except in the case that $password has an @ sign in it; the $username and $passwords variables are gotten from reading stdin

Comment: just double quote the variables

Comment: I think the problem is not in bash but in getting Samba to recognize which '@' is in the password and which '@' marks the end of the password.  And I doubt there's a way to do it, but if there is, you will need to look at the Samba manuals for the information.  'Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I hit myself like this'?  Or, in other words, do not use '@' in the password because it causes grief.

Comment: Maybe try replacing all `@` with `%40`... I don't think it'll work but maybe that's the go. Use `$password=${password//@/%40}` to replace them.

Comment: Yeah good idea dreamlax, but then %40 isn't accepted by my samba server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, no, this isn't actually a matter of quoting for Bash, but quoting for Samba.  You have this:

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER -v smb://$username:$password@SERVER -E
```

which Bash dutifully expands to

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER -v smb://alice:passw@rd@SERVER -E
```

and then the *Samba client library* thinks the password ends at the first @ sign and it's supposed to connect to a server named `rd@server`, never mind that you can't actually put that name in the DNS.

`lpadmin` comes from CUPS, not from Samba ([here is its manpage](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/man-lpadmin.html)) and, reading through those docs a bit, I think you may be able to use this alternate syntax:

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER -U "${username}%${password}" -v smb://SERVER -E
```

I'm surprised escaping `@` as `%40` doesn't work, though.  Looks like a bug in the samba client library to me.

Comment: you're right, it is samba; I've updated the question to reflect what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks!  Updated my answer, may actually have a fix for you.

Answer (score 3):

I use the cups admin at http://localhost:631/ to add printers. Encoding @ as %40 worked for me.